# MySql statement returning incorrect results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to receive an Id from my user table. 
I have:

```
$retrieve_id = "SELECT userid FROM tb_users WHERE username = '$username'";
$user_id = intval(mysql_query($retrieve_id));
```

The statement should return 1 since that is the value in the table. However, it returns 6 which is the length of the column name (`userid`). This happens when I'm querying other tables too.

How can I retrieve the value from the table ONLY?

Comment: `var_dump` your variables. They don't contain what you think they contain.

Comment: what about $user_id=intval(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($retrieve_id));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **fetch** the actual result from the query, either using `mysql_result` or `mysql_fetch_*`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM tb_users WHERE username = '$username'");

if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}

$user_id = mysql_result($result, 0); // outputs first row
```

**Note** that all `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should use `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Your query is also open to SQL injection.

Comment: I'm using mysql_real_escape_string. That's should protect it right?

Comment: @user2742663 See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

mysql_query returns a resource not the value.

```
$retrieve_id = "SELECT userid FROM tb_users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($retrieve_id));
$user = $result['userid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

A) mysql_* is deprecated
B) make sure you're parameterizing your inputs
C) try this:

```
$result = mysql_query($retrieve_id);

$user_id=$result["userid"];
```

Answer (score 0):

function  mysql_query returns resource type for a select query. For results you have to use mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc functions.

```
$retrieve_id = "SELECT userid FROM tb_users WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysql_query($retrieve_id));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['userid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the php docs on [mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). It actually returns a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), not simply the value you are querying for.

But you shouldn't even be using `mysql_query()` as it's deprecated in PHP 5.5, and you don't want to have to redo your code when you upgrade, do you?

Instead, use [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), which will return a [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object. Then from that object, you can retrieve the values you're looking for with [fetch_field()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php)